# should i do branch, stash or stash branch?

Tags: git

I have added debug statements to about 10 framework level classes. As this project has lots of XML based wiring and complex logic, it is hard to debug and understand the flow of things, and so I put some important debug statements. As these are the framework wiring classes, if I use breakpoints as an alternative, it takes many passing of breakpoints for every click every time.

Now, I would like to keep these changes, and do not want to redo them. These classes (that I added these debug statements) are seldom changed.
I used to stash my changes and keep. I am wondering if using a branch for this purpose is more efficient and easy.

I would not call myself as a git expert, still learning.
To me, I at least see 3 options:

1. just stash these and apply when necessary
2. keep a branch with these changes and merge them
3. do a stash branch (do not know if there is any difference from #2)

Anytime I work on a task branch, I would like to bring these changes in, but I cannot commit these (debug) changes anyways. While committing, I will disregard these items.

Any ideas would help me

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by #3. A stash is basically just an unnamed branch, though you can easily *create* a new branch from a stash later (using `git stash branch`).

Comment: @chepner yes, in #3, that is what I meant. I just saw this "stash branch" online, so I asked. You know, I would like to find out which route is better for my use case.

Comment: If your goal is to have a set of debug statements that you can remove and restore over time as your branch evolves, a stash might be the right approach. (You can use `git stash pop`, rather than `git stash drop`, to apply a stash to your committed changes,  then just restore the files.) Keep in mind, though, your stash may not cleanly apply once the code changes significantly. There isn't really a good solution for this problem. You might want to just keep the debug statements in, but provide a run-time setting to disable them until needed.

Comment: I like your idea of committing these changes with a runtime flag. I will discuss with the team on this.

Comment: The other option would be to keep a debug branch that you merge changes *into*, but never otherwise change or merge back to the development branch.